# Attempting to update value in array throwing error MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to update an array in my mongo document.  Want to switch out the value.
within the favorited_by array.  Want to switch out 5170049 for 81952455 and I am using this command in MongoShell but receiving this error

MongoShell command

```
db.messages.updateOne({_id: "140449331274573645", favorited_by: "5170049"}, {$set: {{"favorited_by.$": "81952455"}})
```

Error

```
Error: clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.
    at Object.serialize (node:v8:332:7)
    at u (/Applications/MongoDB Compass.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@mongosh/node-runtime-worker-thread/dist/worker-runtime.js:1917:594983)
    at postMessage (/Applications/MongoDB Compass.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@mongosh/node-runtime-worker-thread/dist/worker-runtime.js:1917:595591)
    at i (/Applications/MongoDB Compass.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@mongosh/node-runtime-worker-thread/dist/worker-runtime.js:1917:600488)
```

Document

```
{
  "_id": "140449331274573645",
  "attachments": [],
  "avatar_url": "https://test",
  "created_at": 1404493312,
  "favorited_by": [
    "11666391",
    "5170049"
  ],
  "group_id": "12345",
  "name": "John Smith",
  "sender_id": "19187160",
  "sender_type": "user",
  "source_guid": "android-a6ce72e8-79a7-4714-8ede-4741c141047f",
  "system": false,
  "text": "sample",
  "user_id": "123456",
  "pinned_at": null,
  "pinned_by": "",
  "create_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1660760105066"
    }
  },
  "date_time": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1404478912000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working here https://mongoplayground.net/p/ogO2DNUcSI6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of @Charchit Kapoor's clue in the comments, the problem is a minor syntax issue. The command posted in the question has:

```
... {$set: {{"favorited_by.$" ...
```

It's the double `{{` that is the problem. Removing one of them (which is similarly absent in the playground example from the comments) resolves the issue:

```
>db.foo.updateOne({_id: "140449331274573645", favorited_by: "5170049"}, {$set: {{"favorited_by.$": "81952455"}})
    Error: clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.
>db.foo.updateOne({_id: "140449331274573645", favorited_by: "5170049"}, {$set: {"favorited_by.$": "81952455"}})
{ acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedCount: 0 }
>db.foo.findOne({},{favorited_by:1})
{ _id: '140449331274573645',
  favorited_by: [ '11666391', '81952455' ] }
```